# JDBC Unable to Connect with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, raspbian

I'm using JDBC (inside of Google Apps Script) to connect to a remote MySQL server that I created on a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Lite), but I'm unable to establish a connection when I run this command: `var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://[Raspberry Pi's IP Address]:3306/[Database Name]", "username", "password");`

Where "username" and "password" is the login info for my MySQL database.

I have followed the steps necessary for MySQL remote access suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql). These include:

- Commenting out the bind-address from the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` file. The common locations for the configuration file containing the bind-address value (e.g. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) didn't exist on the Raspberry Pi, so I ended up finding the file listed above.
- Enabling remote root access to the MySQL database.
- And, using `telnet` on the Raspberry Pi. The message: "Connection closed by foreign host." occurs when I use it, however, and I'm unaware of what that message could mean.

What do you think is preventing a connection to the database from being established?

Comment: Is your Raspberry PI accessible over the internet? What IP address are you using?

Comment: I just used `nmcli general status` on my Raspberry Pi and found that it is disconnected from the internet, although I have configured its Wi-Fi connection already. I may need to look into that. The IP address I'm using is the Raspberry Pi's (the server host's) IP: a 192.168 number.

Comment: A 192.168.x.x address is a local network address that is not routable over the internet.

Comment: Since I'm making a connection within my local network, shouldn't that be the IP I use?

Comment: Google Apps Script runs in the cloud on Google's servers.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks a lot!